# Lambda - Store/Pass Redshift Connection

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I will be deploying nearly 300-400 Lambda parallelly to achieve one of my desired expectations.
These are very small calculations that needs to be performed which needs the calculation data to be read from Redshift.
The only challenge which I am not able to solve is how I will pass the Redshift Connection to each of the Lambda because I will not create a separate connection for each Lambda over Redshift since this will bring down my cluster in terms of connection.
I will be using the `pycopg2` library to connect with my Redshift Cluster.

The question is :

- Is it possible to pass Redshift Connection across all the Lambda Functions?
- Is it possible to store the Connection details in a central location from where my Lambda Function can read it and then make a query to Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

Connection is a session from a specific client, and each of your Lambda functions is a separate client, so you can't use the same connection. If you run 300-400 Lambdas in parallel you might want to reconsider doing that.

As for storing connection details you have SSM parameter store where you can store either the whole connection string or individual pieces.

Answer (score 0):

We use `secretsmanager` to store our connection information.

Here's a sample python code that we use, just replace <secret_name> with your secret.

```py
        # Get connection info
        scm = boto3.client("secretsmanager")
        r = scm.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=<secret_name>,
        )

        cred = r['SecretString']
        cred = json.loads(cred)

        # Connecting to DB
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=cred['host'],
            port=cred['port'],
            dbname=cred['dbname'],
            user=cred['username'],
            password=cred['password'],
        )
```

Comment: I want to store the entire connection object, connection details is not a issue.